# Why is GGally plotting incorrect values with the ggparcoord() function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I am currently trying to make a parallel coordinate plot in R with the `GGally` package. Below is my code (I have deleted the aesthetic changes such as `theme()`).

```
ggparcoord(ts, # dataframe
           columns = c(3:4, 9, 11:12), # Selecting the variables listed in the plot (x-axis)
           groupColumn = 20, # Grouping by album
           alphaLines = .75,
           showPoints = TRUE)
```

This plots a fine graph, except it shows incorrect values. I have attached the plot below. I also ran a `summary()` function on the different variables and noted the discrepancies. When I run:

```
summary(ts$danceability)
```

I get:

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.2920  0.5155  0.5940  0.5846  0.6455  0.8970
```

These values are clearly not reflected accurately in the plot. What is going wrong here?
Also, in order to clean the graph up, how could I make it interactive on HTML to where someone could select whichever album they would prefer to analyze on its own?

[image: Parallel Coord Plot]

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by including data: paste the output of `dput(ts)` into the question. This link may be helpful: [Reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `ggparcoord` scales the original values. According to the docs you can prevent (or rather: neutralize) scaling by setting the scale option to: `ggparcoord(..., scale = "globalminmax")`. On a sidenote: you're not going to throw this plot at a real-life audience, are you? ;-)

Comment: @I_O No, definitely not. That is why I am trying to get it to where the user can select which album they would like to focus on. Currently doing ```facet_grid( ~ album_name)``` but that leads to each section being super squished. Not exactly sure how I can best visualize this data. Thank you for the note about the scale however, did not know it automatically scaled!

Comment: Not an easy task! For static display, **{ggridges}** might be an option: https://wilkelab.org/ggridges/articles/introduction.html For interactive display, **{highcharter}** offers a *drilldown*, e.g. displaying a barplot of average scores per album and zooming in to score per category and album on mouseclick: https://jkunst.com/highcharter/ . Both will require some tinkering, though.